# Create input as child of input

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Is it possible to create a button that is the child of an text?

```
<input type="text">
    <input type="button" />
</input>
```

The reason I ask is I would like to make a combo box. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw6FQ/1/). Doing this in jquery, the button does not appear. Doing it in regular html, the 2nd input is not a child of the first (in Chrome at least).

I could put a text and button in a span, but I prefer to create the text box like in the example so later the value can be retrieved like: $("#test).val();

PS I know other combo box plugins exist. I would like to roll my own for learning purposes.

Comment: That is an invalid html. You cannot have something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will result in invalid HTML, so its not possible to do this.
What you can do is create a div, which is a block element and fill it with a text box + button Inline elements.

With some styling in your CSS you can make your div look like a textbox and your textbox like a div, without borders and bevels. Resulting in something that looks like the thing you are trying to achieve here.

To get rid of the textbox look on your input use `#YourTextBox {border: none;}`

Answer (score 10):

This is not possible as `input` is an inline element - it cannot have children.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is that the `input` tag is a [void element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) that cannot have any children. Inline elements such as span can have children.

> Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified
>   for void elements.

i.e. in HTML5 there can never be a closing tag for an  i.e. don't use `</input>`. HTML5 is not XML and it strongly discourages self-closing tags (`/>`) i.e. `<input />` is not strictly correct HTML5 (although it will work for compatibility purposes). The list of void element tags defined in HTML5 are: `area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr`.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be a valid approach to nest HTML elements in that way. If you take a look at what jQuery plugins do, they usually wrap your `<select>` element with divs and other stuff. IMHO, you can solve the problem by following a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

Inputs can't have children because they do not end.
Here's some info: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp