# Get HTML Code of Element (innerHTML + element tags)

Tags: javascript, html

How to get HTML code of element in JavaScript with current element tags?

For example

```
<body><div><div class="big"><p>sometext</p></div></div></body>

var x = document.getElementsByClassName('big')[0]
```

and now I want get HTML code of x :

```
'<div class="big"><p>sometext</p></div>'
```

not only:

```
'<p>sometext</p>' like innerHTML.
```

Is there simpler method than that?

```
var div = document.createElement("div"); 
div.id='_fooo'; var parent = x.parentNode; 
parent.insertBefore(div, x); 
div.appendChild(x); 
document.getElementById('_fooo').innerHTML
```

Comment: [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML), though [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) is an empty element and can't have HTML or any other content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your html block has an error. `<input>` is an empty element, and it cannot have child elements. So,

```
<input type="submit" class="big"><p>sometext</p></input>
```

is not a valid HTML.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629410/create-input-as-child-of-input](http://See%20details)

Anyway, the answer to your question is 'outerHTML' attribute.

Replacing your `<input>` tag with `<div>`

```
<div type="submit" class="big"><p>sometext</p></div>

var x = document.getElementsByClassName('big')[0];
var output = x.outerHTML // returns '<div type="submit" class="big"><p>sometext</p></div>'
```

Comment: An element being an inline element doesn't mean it couldn't have content, most of the inline elements can have content. An empty element (previously known as void element) would be a correct term.

Answer (score 0):

Get the parent of your current element and call get innerHTML on that, but that will give you all the children, so you might want to create a parent div for your element just so you can read it's content.

example

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('big')[0].parentElement.innerHTML
```

here your parent will be the body based on the given example, and it will get the next inside it which is what you want.

Comment: I know this method, but what if i have more childrens? 

Is There not simpler method than that?

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id='_fooo';
var parent = this.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore(div, this);
div.appendChild(this);

document.getElementById('_fooo').innerHTML

Comment: try the outerhtml idea on the input element, that might give you exactly what you need